# "A promise chain failed to handle a rejection" while loading add-on

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm developing a Firefox add-on with content scripts that include jquery, [a single script containing my code object](https://github.com/groovecoder/firefox-addon/blob/codesy-js-refactor/data/codesy.js), and [a launch script](https://github.com/groovecoder/firefox-addon/blob/codesy-js-refactor/data/launch.js) to activate the class when the window location matches certain patterns:

https://github.com/groovecoder/firefox-addon/tree/codesy-js-refactor

Whenever I launch Firefox with this add-on, I get a strange error that seems to come from the Add-on SDK itself?

```
20:58:23.165 XPIDatabase.connection is undefined main.js:42
20:58:23.228 [object Object] runner.js:162
20:58:23.232 [object Object] promise.js:133
20:58:33.346 A promise chain failed to handle a rejection.

Date: Sat Jan 25 2014 20:58:23 GMT-0600 (CST)
Full Message: Unix error 17 during operation makeDir (File exists)
```

No part of my add-on executes - even an `alert("Hello")` at the very beginning of `lib/main.js` is never reached or executed.

Answer (score 2):

There is a syntax error here:

https://github.com/groovecoder/firefox-addon/blob/codesy-js-refactor/lib/main.js#L14

...you'll want to remove the semi-colon. That should get the add-on loading, at least.

Comment: Good catch, thanks! That cleared up the add-on loading and executing.

Any idea what could be causing the other error(s)?